# Menu Transition CSS

Tags: css

My issue is that when the page is loading, if the mouse is sitting over where the drop-down would appear, it opens the menu where as i don't want the menu opening unless the pointer is over the menu-option (ie info, home etc...)

My website menu currently uses CSS so that when I hover the menu option, the drop-down fades in:

```
.mega-menu{
    visibility:none;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0
    transform: TranslateY(-.5em);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s,visibility 0s linear 0.3s,z-index 0s linear .1s;
}

.mega-menu:hover
.mega-drop-down a:hover+.mega-menu,
.mega-drop-down a:hover + .tab-content{
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:999;
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear 0.3s;
}

.mega-drop-down:hover .tab-pane.active, .mega-drop-down:hover .container-fluid, .mega-drop-down:hover .list-inline > li{
visibility:visible !important;
}
```

I tried using `display:none` and `display:block`

but then it losses the transition effect

is there anything that can be done so that the transition still happens and the problem with the menu showing while page is loading is combated?

Update:
Menu:

```
<nav class="content">
    <ul class="exo-menu">
        <li><a class="active menhome" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#" onclick="return false"><i class="fa"></i> Mega-drop-down</a>
            <div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
                <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="Featured">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline list-inline2">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline list-inline2">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline list-inline2">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Before the DOM has fully loaded, you could use `display:none`. Then when the DOM has fully loaded, change to `display: block`.

The issue with the display property losing animation is this CSS property does not support animations.

The idea here is to prevent the behavior you are seeing prior to load, then after load it should work as you have it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: in order to use `z-index` the element must have a `position` other than `static` (the default). Can you add your HTML of the menu in question? You say _when I hover the menu option, the drop-down fades in_ but your CSS looks like when you hover a invisible `menu-option` it shows that `menu-option`... not a drop-down.

Comment: @zgood My menu uses `position:relative` so I am assuming that the z-index should then work? I will add the HTML now...

Comment: @Illdapt That would be perfect but I am unsure how to do that (I am still a beginner lol :-). i amquessing that would involve JQuery such as `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem from looking further into @Illdapt.

I added `.hidden class` and `wrapper ID` to:

```
<div class="animated fadeIn mega-menu">
```

so it reads:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hidden">
```

with:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

and used the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#wrapper').removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

This then removes the hidden class when the DOM has loaded and solves the above problem.

thanks again @Illdapt